# React - how to update a nested object when the keys are variables

Tags: reactjs

To be honest I am not even 100% that this is my problem - it could simply be that I have the structure wrong. But this is what I am trying to do:

```
Team :
{
    1 : {
            name: "Joe",
            items: ['hat', 'gloves']
        },
    2 : {
            name: "Kate",
            items: ['bonnet']
        }
}

const [team, setTeam] = useState(Team);
```

There could be any number of people in the team. There could be any number of items in the items collection.

I know the number of the person e.g. 1 for Jim and I know the index of the items array I want to change and the new value.

This is a simplified example but it is exactly the problem.

So, let's say I want to replace Joe's gloves with mittens:

```
function update(teamNumber, itemNumber, newItem) {

    let newItems = Team[teamNumber].items.map( (val, idx) => {
            if (idx == itemNumber) 
            {
                return newItem;
            }
            else
            {
                return val;
            }
    });

    setTeam(

         (prevState) => { 
                return {...prevState,
                    teamNumber : {
                    ...prevState[teamNumber],
                    items : newItems
                }
            };

        }
    )

}
```

There are two separate problems:

1. How to update the specific index element in the array. I have not even tried to do that in the state setter - I try to do it separately in the map routine.
2. There seems to be a problem using a variable, teamNumber as a key in the state setter. At least when I run with this code it appears to wipe state (at least nothing is displayed in the bound input field) but if I use a specific number e.g. 1 for teamNumber then it appears to work.

I could live with 1. But 2. is a blocker. (My workaround is to do a clean unlinked copy of the whole object - there are more fields - and replace it completely).

Another approach might be to "flatten the state" - i can see that; but, again, I can't create a set variable for each team member because they are variable..

Thank you

Comment: Use `[teamNumber]: {...prevState[teamNumber], items : newItems}` to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your key in bracket to make it dynamic as Unmitigated mention:

```
function update(teamNumber, itemNumber, newItem) {
  let newItems = team[teamNumber].items.map((val, idx) => {
    if (idx === itemNumber) {  // use === for a strict equality
      return newItem;
    } else {
      return val;
    }
  });

  setTeam((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [teamNumber]: {
      ...prevState[teamNumber],
      items: newItems,
    },
  }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I marked as correct because part 2 of my problem, the blocker, is solved by the simple expedient of adding [] around the key. Also thanks to @Unmitigated

Answer (score 1):

I would just reset the state like this. It is a little verbose but should do the job. Let me know if you need me to explain this in more depth:

```
setState(prev => {
  ...prev, 
  teamNumber: {
    ...prev[teamNumber],
    items: [...prev[teamNumber].items.slice(0, itemNumber), newItem, 
      ...prev[teamNumber].items.slice(itemNumber + 1, 
      prev[teamNumber].items.length)]
  }
})
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to quite work. I end up with [undefined, undefined] in the items array. Can you explain it a bit more; probably it is me. - I think you are trying to build a new array and replace one element in it with the new value?

Comment: Ah. it works. In my code I was using e.currentTarget.value for newItem and it seems to have lost track of that. Now I assign that to a variable outside of setState and use that in place of newItem and it works. I can follow logically your scheme - you are taking a slice or the array, adding in the new item, and then another slice. It itemNumber is say 1 - we have: oldFirstItem, newItem, oldThirdItem. Thanks, Sorry not to mark yours as correct but, strictly speaking the index problem was greater.. This is the icing on the cake.